# SPS3 crawl SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am struggling to get search service to crawl through sharepoint people. When i add SPS3://server I get an error in the log that object does not exists. I made sure the permissions are correct and i am able to crawl HTTP ://server with no problems. I made sure firewall is not in the way as well. Profile service is working as expected and all profiles have been imported into SP. my site collection is configured as seems to be working properly as well. It doesn't seem there is a lot of info out there for SPS3 crawl throwing that error. I see STS4://server is being crawled crawled properly as well. Any idea would be appreciated. I am lost at this point.

Comment: Could you please post the exact error as it appears in 'Crawl Log'

Comment: The exact error msg is: The object was not found. ( SearchID = xxxxx)
I have tried using fqdn and just host name in address.

Comment: Just to add. I re-created user profile service and search service applications. re-added perms everywhere and the issue is still present. Doesn't seem to be an issue with the services themselves.
I can navigate to _vti_bin/spscrawl.asmx so i think the service is working but I am not able to get WSDL page for it (or any service). Not sure if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming search service application and user profile service is otherwise functional.

You will need to check 3 things:-

1) Make sure that the default content access account (crawl account) has access to the User Profile Service

- Select the User Profile Service Application and click on
  Administrators Add your content access account and give it the
  Retrieve People Data for Search Crawlers permission

2) Make sure that the default content access account (crawl account) has access to the Search service.

- Select the Search Service Application and click on Administrators Add
  your content access account and give it the Full control permission

3) Make sure that the default content access account (crawl account) has access to the web applications that are crawling.

- Select the web application -> check the user policy on Ribbon Add
  your content access account and give it the Full control permission

The full article with additonal fixes is located at:-

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/25863.access-is-denied-verify-that-either-the-default-content-access-account-has-access-to-this-repository-or-add-a-crawl-rule-to-crawl-this-repository.aspx

Comment: Thanks. permissions are set correctly (web application perms were set full read as i thought was the proper perm for it. I tried it with full control and had the same results).
None of the errors in the article match one i'm seeing but i have looked through it.
Solution 4 does describe ou configuration. We have a WFE, App and search servers in a farm. The host file update piece of the host header configuration has been completed using DNS records rather than local hosts file.